# Color coding in VBA throwing errors

Tags: vba, excel

The color coding in this code has been throwing errors and is not giving me the desired outputs. The code should provide outputs in red and green but unfortunately it is not doing so even after several attempts

```
Sub FillValues()


    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
'EUS Values by Case
If Ws.Range("G5") <> "" Then
   Ws.Range("G5").Copy Ws.Cells(15, 9)

        Select Case Ws.Range("G5").Value
                Case Is < "25%"
                Ws.Range("I15").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                
        End Select
Else
        
        Select Case Ws.Range("G5").Value
                Case Is > "25%", Is < "50%"
                Ws.Range("I15").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End Select
        
        Select Case Ws.Range("G5").Value
                Case Is < "25%"
                Ws.Range("I15").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End Select

  End If
        'Trials by IF Condition
        ' If Ws.Range("G5").Value < "25%" Then Ws.Range("I15").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            
        'ElseIf Ws.Range("G5").Value > "25%" And Ws.Range("G5").Value < "50%" Then Ws.Range("I15").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            
        'ElseIf Ws.Range("G5").Value > "50%" Then Ws.Range("I15").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        
        'End If
        
        'HOST Values

'If Ws.Range("G6") <> "" Then
'   Ws.Range("G6").Copy Ws.Cells(16, 9)
'
'    If Ws.Range("G6").Value < "25%" Then Ws.Range("I16").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
'
'    ElseIf Ws.Range("G6").Value > "25%" And Ws.Range("G6").Value < "50%" Then Ws.Range("I16").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
'
'    ElseIf Ws.Range("G6").Value > "50%" Then Ws.Range("I16").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
'


'End If

'HOST Values By Case

If Ws.Range("G6") <> "" Then
   Ws.Range("G6").Copy Ws.Cells(16, 9)

        Select Case Ws.Range("G6").Value
                Case Is < "25%"
                Ws.Range("I16").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End Select
        Else
        
        Select Case Ws.Range("G6").Value
                Case Is > "25%", Is < "50%"
                Ws.Range("I16").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End Select
        
        Select Case Ws.Range("G6").Value
                Case Is < "25%"
                Ws.Range("I16").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End Select

  End If
  
  'MNS Values

If Ws.Range("G7") <> "" Then
   Ws.Range("G7").Copy Ws.Cells(17, 9)

        Select Case Ws.Range("G7").Value
                Case Is < "25%"
                Ws.Range("I17").Interior.ColorIndex = 4
        End Select
        
        Else
        
        Select Case Ws.Range("G7").Value
                Case Is > "25%", Is < "50%"
                Ws.Range("I17").Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        End Select
        
        Select Case Ws.Range("G7").Value
                Case Is > "25%"
                Ws.Range("I17").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End Select

  End If

End Sub
```

Comment: A percentage is stored as a decimal (even though it shows as a whole number with a percentage sign). Try `Case Is < .25` and `CASE .25 to .50`. Also... why are you using a `SELECT CASE` when you only have one `CASE` condition. Instead just use an If.

Comment: @JNevill Hey man! Thanks for the solution. Definitely seems simpler. Can you tell me how you are defining “i” parameter ?

Comment: `i` is defined by the `For` loop. It's value changed each loop, starting at 5, then 6 then 7 then the loop ends. (posted in the comments to the answer too)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick rewrite that makes use of a for loop so you don't have code duplication. It also fixes the tests to test for decimals instead of string percentages (which I assume is your problem):

```
Sub FillValues()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For i = 5 to 7
        'EUS Values by Case
        If Ws.Range("G" & i) <> "" Then
            Ws.Range("G" & i).Copy Ws.Cells(10+i, 9)        
            If Ws.Range("G" & i).Value < .25 Then 
                Ws.Range("I1" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 4          
            End If
        Else

                Select Case Ws.Range("G" & i).Value
                    Case .25 to .50
                        Ws.Range("I1" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                    Case Is < .25                   
                        Ws.Range("I1" & i).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End Select

        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Alternatively (preferred by me):

```
Sub FillValues()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


    Dim rngCell as Range        
    For each rngCell in Ws.Range("G5:G7").Cells
        If rngCell <> "" Then
            rngCell.Copy rngCell.Offset(10, 2)     
            If rngCell.Value < .25 Then 
                rngCell.Offset(10, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4          
            End If
        Else
            Select Case rngCell.Value
                Case .25 to .50
                    rngCell.Offset(10, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                Case Is < .25                   
                    rngCell.Offset(10, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End Select
        End If
    Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Here's the same code, with lots of comments explaining each action:

```
Sub FillValues()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    'Declare a new range variable called rngCell
    Dim rngCell as Range    

    'Using a "For Each" loop, loop through each cell in the range 
    '   Ws.Range("G5:G7") (Three cells). During each iteration 
    '   of this loop assign the cell being processed to the
    '   variable "rngCell". 
    For each rngCell in Ws.Range("G5:G7").Cells

        'Check to see if rngCell (G5, G6, or G7) is set to "" (empty)
        If rngCell <> "" Then

            'It's empty so copy it to the cell that is 10 rows down and 2 rows right
            rngCell.Copy rngCell.Offset(10, 2)  

            'If its value is less than .25 then set the cell that is 10 rows down
            '   and 2 rows right to colorindex 4 (Bright Green probably)
            If rngCell.Value < .25 Then 
                rngCell.Offset(10, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4          
            End If

        Else 'If the cell wasn't blank then do this code

            'As an alternative to the IF statement we can use SELECT Case
            '   So test rngCell's value and do something based on that
            Select Case rngCell.Value

                'Test rngCell's value. If it's between .25 and .50 then set 
                '   the color of the cell that is 10 rows down and 2 columns
                '   to the right to have a colorindex of 6 (Bright Yellow, probably)
                Case .25 to .50
                    rngCell.Offset(10, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6

                'If instead the value of rngCell is less than .25 then set
                '   the color of the cell that is 10 rows down and 2 columns
                '   to the right to have a colorindex of 3 (Bright Red, probably)
                Case Is < .25                   
                    rngCell.Offset(10, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End Select
        End If

    'Tell the for loop to go on to the next cell in Ws.Range("G5:G7").cells
    Next rngCell

    'The loop is finished so we are going to end the sub.
End Sub
```

Comment: `i` is defined by the `For` loop. It's value changed each loop, starting at 5, then 6 then 7 then the loop ends.

Comment: Similarly the For loop in the second example changes the value of the `rngCell` variable from `G5` to `G6` to `G7`. `rngCell` is an actual object so it has all the parameters/attributes and methods/functions of the range it's standing for.

Comment: I am trying to run this code but it gives me the error "invalid next control variable reference"

Comment: Apologies. That second set of code should read `Next rngCell` not `next i`. I will update the answer.

Comment: The code executes now but it is only copying the values and not coloring all of them except one. Trying to understand the code better. :/

Comment: I've made a minor change in the second code to insure the color is being applied to the correct cell. I've also added a TON of comments to the second code and pasted that below the original answer to explain each step. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks man! I modified the code a bit and now it is working :)